# Only admins can be selected as author of custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'products', and when I go to create a new product post, it only allows me to select admins from the Author dropdown list. I previously had this working with the following code, but it's no longer working anymore with a recent update. I have a custom user type, called 'business-owner', which I would like to be included in the Author drop down for my CPT.

```
function pbt_add_members_to_dropdown( $query_args, $r ) {
   
    $query_args['role'] = array('business-owner');
   
    // Unset the 'who' as this defaults to the 'author' role
    unset( $query_args['who'] );
   
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', 'pbt_add_members_to_dropdown', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Maybe related? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/#comment-6209